# Object ordering within a sentence

Tags: sentence-structure, grammatical-case, word-order

Objects in the sentence are ordered in a particular way. In the below sentences the Objects are always in the dative case (indirect objects).

1. *Tim ist auf dem Weg zur Schule mit seinen Freunden.*

Here *dem Weg* und *der Schule* are dative, following the respective prepositions. Is this correct?

The same with the below sentence. *Dem Haus* before *mit dem Hund*.

2. *Damit er nicht mehr an dem Haus mit dem Hund vorbei gehen musste..*

What is order of Objects in a sentence.

Comment: German word order is not fixed except for the positioning of the verbs. They can be moved around pretty freely for emphasis.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity however, I know only this basic sentence structure *subject+verb+Indirect Object+Direct Object+ seprableverb*. means a sentence can hold only indirect object(s) without direct object(s) and vice versa?

Comment: Remove that ‘basic sentence structure’ out of your head for a number of reasons: 1) German does not have ‘direct’ and ‘indirect’ objects but dative and accusative objects. 2) Verbs may or may not require a dative object and they may or may not require an accusative object; for example *jemande**m** helfen*takes dative only. 3) It depends on the nature of the objects. ‘Ich schenke ihm ein Buch’ is the less emphasised order but the dative object is before the accusative object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original formulation was not very clear; I will answer your question as I understood it.

Sentence 1: The order of the two phrases *auf dem Weg zur Schule* and *mit seinen Freunden* is arbitrary. You can equally well say *Tim ist mit seinen Freunden auf dem Weg zur Schule.* The order depends on where you want to place the emphasis, on his location or on the fact that his friends are with him. Please note that they are not **objects**, they are adjuncts. You can leave them out without much changing the meaning of the sentence. Obviously one of them needs to remain for the sentence to work.

Sentence 2: There are two readings here. The first, more obvious one IMO, is that there is a house with a dog, and he does not want to walk past it. In that case the whole lot is a single phrase, *das Haus mit dem Hund*. It is in the dative because of the preposition *an*. There is no possibility of swapping the order of the two elements.

The second option is that he is walking the dog, and he does not want to walk past that particular house. In that case it would be preferable to say *damit er nicht mehr mit dem Hund an dem Haus vorbeigehen musste*, to make it obvious that the dog is not part of the house. So here you have a free choice, but depending on the meaning there is a strong preference for one of them.

Comment: From the basic grammar for sentence construction  **subject+verb+Indirect Object+Direct Object+ seprableverb.**  Sentence 1 doesnt suffice the rule. Holds the same for sentence 2 which is neben satz

Comment: @user755 They aren't indirect objects, though. An example with a direct object would be _Tim gibt seinem Freund ein Brot ab_. ("Tim shares a bread with his friend"). Here the word order is fixed.

Comment: Are you implying ‘Tim gibt ein Brot seinem Freund ab’ be invalid? (CC @user755 ).

Comment: @Jan It definitely sounds odd to me. Not totally wrong, you could for example have _Tim gibt einen Teil davon seinem Freund ab_, which to me sounds perfectly fine. So I guess it's the _abgeben_ that clashes with the _Brot_ here.

Comment: The order of objects depends primarily on meaning. If one of the two objects contains more surprising information, it normally comes last. As a result, if only one object is represented by a pronoun (hence noun already), it normally comes first: "Tim gibt *es* seinem Freund ab. - Tim gibt *ihm* eines ab." Similarly if one object has a definite article and the other an indefinite one: "Tim gibt *das Brot* einem Freund. - Tim gibt *dem Freund* ein Brot." (Italics mark here what was mentioned before.) The opposite order is possible, but is reserved for special emphasis in unusual cases.

Comment: What I just said explains why "Tim gibt ein Brot seinem Freund ab" sounds slightly unusual. In *sein Freund*, *sein* functions like a definite article. The friend is known - what is new is the bread, which probably wasn't mentioned before. So it's the wrong order. - EXCEPT if the bread is actually one of several that were mentioned before. In that case there is a strong emphasis on *ein*, and the word order is perfectly natural: "Tim gibt **ein** Brot seinem Freund ab. Die anderen behält er." (Though the other word order is possible even with this meaning, as both objects are already known.)